# Lingering No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error with S3

Tags: amazon-s3, cors

I'm having a weird issue loading assets from S3. I have a stylesheet that's being served from S3 and seems to be loading with no issues, but I'm still getting a `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` error in the console. The assets are public, and here's the CORS configuration on my bucket

```
<CORSRule>
  <AllowedOrigin>MYDOMAINHERE</AllowedOrigin>
  <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
  <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
  <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
```

Again, the styles are all loading and everything seems to be fine but I'm just trying to figure out why it would still be throwing that error and hoping to eliminate it if possible. Thanks!

Comment: The value for `<AllowedOrigin>` must begin with `http://` or `https://`.  Do you have that, and does it match the operational mode of your site (http/https)?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, should have specified that. I have two `<AllowedOrigin>` specifications - one for http and one for https. MYDOMAINHERE was just mean to be a placeholder.

Comment: It could just be due to the browser having cached that stylesheet and continuing to serve it from its cache. So maybe try force-reloading the stylesheet URL in your browser, to get the browser to re-load it over the network instead of from its cached copy. If that doesn’t fix it I guess it’s also possible that you have some network cache/proxy in between that’s still serving up a stale copy. But if so, not sure how to suggest fixing that…

Comment: Show us the captured request and response headers?  There's an issue with CORS handling in S3 that can contribute to what @sideshowbarker is proposing.

Comment: @sideshowbarker michael-sqlbot I think that was exactly the issue. The error seems to have disappeared on certain pages (like the homepage) so the server must have been caching the old version. Just a waiting game I guess! If one of you wants to answer I can mark it as correct!

Comment: OK—posted a general answer since I’m not familiar with the specifics might be in this case. Regardless, glad to hear the error is going away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior described in the question is most likely due to either the browser having cached the resource and continuing to serve it from its cache or else something on the server side or an intermediate network proxy/cache is still serving a stale copy.

If the caching problem is on the client side you try navigating to the URL for the resource directly in your browser and then force-reloading it.

But if the problem’s with a cache/proxy on the network side, it can be more difficult to get a fresh copy. In those cases you may just have to wait for the cache to expire. Looking at the values of the `Expires` and `Cache-Control` response headers can give you an idea when that will happen.